# IBM Watson Conversation: Patterns with (smart) quotes

Tags: regex, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I am trying to [define a pattern-based entity in the Conversation service](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#defining-entities). The pattern is meant to capture a string between double quotes. I have defined the following regular expression for that entity:

```
\"[A-Za-z0-9.:| @\\']+\"
```

On my Linux box everything worked fine, but it does not seem to work from other environments like a Mac. The quotes are not recognized and hence the pattern does not match. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A likely reason for that error or behavior are **smart quotes** (which are not always a smart idea). On some systems or in some apps double quotes (`"`) are converted into either `“` and `”` or `„` and `“`. I recommend extending the pattern to include such quotes:

```
[\"„“][A-Za-z0-9.:| @\\']+[\"”“]
```

That way the Watson Conversation service detects the beginning and ending double quotes regardless of whether smart quotes are enabled or not. I have used such a pattern successfully for a [chatbot interacting with Slack in this tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html).